# Trying to move a button using JS functions

Tags: javascript, html

For a school project, when the user clicks the initial login button it is removed and a new one appears and then descends for 2 seconds down 100 pixels. I'm sure there is probably a much more efficient way of doing this but for now not quite sure, any help would be appreciated.

```js
function hideForm() {
  document.getElementById("loginForm").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("LoginButtonS").style.display = "none";
}


function moveLogin() {
  document.getElementById("login").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("register").style.display = "none"; /* Hides original Register as login ioption selected*/


  document.getElementById("LoginButtonS").style.display = "block"; /*Gets button that can actually complete an action sequence as the other will not work. */
  document.getElementById("LoginButtonS").translateY = (-100);
  document.getElementById("LoginButtonS").style.transitionDuration = "2s";

  //document.getElementById("loginForm").style.display = "block"; /*Shows the form after Login button has moved down*/


}
```

```html
<html>

<title>Database Website Name</title>


<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jsscripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body onLoad="hideForm()">
  <div class="window">
    <!-- window is imaginary box around the two buttons -->

    <p class="windowtext">
      <!-- the first buttons -->
      <button id="login" onclick="moveLogin()" class="buttonl">Login</button><br>
      <button id="register" onclick="moveRegister(register)" class="buttonr">Register</button>
    </p>



    <form id="loginForm" class="loginForm">
      <!-- Text boxes and submit buttons -->

      <div class="windowtext">

        <input class="textbox" type="text" name="ID" placeholder="User ID"><br><br>
        <input class="textbox" type="text" name="Password" placeholder="Password">

        <button class="buttonl" id="LoginButtonS" type="submit">Login <!-- new login button -->
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I apologise if its a dumb mistake ahah

Comment: I think you should have 2 css classes that do all your style manipulations, then you use javascript to change the class on button click

Comment: Instead of calling the button 3 times on the ID. Give it a js-class and use a variable for it. 

for html class="js-LoginButtonS"
in the js: const button = document.querySelector('js-LoginButtonS')

For the styling create use two classes like d-block and d-none and you can toggle between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add/Remove classes instead of adding inline css. And use opacity instead of display property.

**CSS**

```
.horizTranslate {
  -webkit-transition: 3s;
  -moz-transition: 3s;
  -ms-transition: 3s;
  -o-transition: 3s;
  transition: 3s;
  transform: translateY(100px);
 }
 .hideButton{
  opacity:0;
 }
 .showButton{
  opacity:1;
 }
```

**JS**

```
function hideForm(){
  document.getElementById("loginForm").classList.add('hideButton')
  document.getElementById("LoginButtonS").classList.add('hideButton');
}
function moveLogin() {
  document.getElementById("login").classList.add('hideButton');
  document.getElementById("register").classList.add('hideButton'); 

  document.getElementById("loginForm").classList.add('showButton');
  document.getElementById("LoginButtonS").classList.add('showButton');
  document.getElementById("LoginButtonS").classList.add('horizTranslate')
}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

CSS is your ally in this story. Instead of changing the *inline CSS* with JavaScript you can add, remove or toggle classes on your elements. These classes should contain styling for the element.

So for example, instead of setting the `transform` property on JS you can create a class which has the transform values in it. Now if you want to apply these styles you can do so by adding a class to the element.

The example below is doing that exact thing. The styles are defined in the CSS and the element is showing and moving based on what class it has at that moment.

You can manipulate the class of an element with the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property on an element. The `classList` property has methods like [`add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add), [`remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove) and [`toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) to change the classes.

Checkout the snippet below. If you have any questions or I've been unclear, please let me know.

```js
const showButton = document.querySelector('.js-show');
const hiddenButton = document.querySelector('.js-hidden');

showButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  hiddenButton.classList.toggle('is-showing');
});
```

```css
button.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, -100px, 0);
  transition-property: opacity, visibility, transform;
  transition-duration: 500ms, 500ms, 2s;
}

button.hidden.is-showing {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<button class="js-show">Toggle button</button>
<button class="js-hidden hidden">Hello there</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a css file called with this

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
```

So lets use it. first You could use a class for set the initial state of the hidden form in the css file.The reason I use "opacity: 0" instead of "display:none" its beacuse with display:none the animation will not work

```
.loginForm {
 opacity: 0;
}
```

With this now you can remove the onLoad function from your < body > tag and from de .js file  completely.

Second there is no need to hide the two first buttons individually beacuse they share the same parent that have the class "windowtext", so you could use a querySelector like this and then it will be only one line of code.
So instead of

```
  document.getElementById("login").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("register").style.display = "none"; /* Hides original 
  Register as login ioption selected*/
```

You can do this

```
document.querySelector('.windowtext').style.display = "none";
```

querySelector allow you to get an element by his class instead of his id

Now for make the second button move for 2 seconds down 100 pixels you could add a new class in the second button like this (I add the "new-button")

```
<button class="buttonl new-button" id="LoginButtonS" type="submit">Login <!-- new 
login button -->
```

And then in the css file add this

```
.new-button{
 display: block;
 transition: all 2s ease-in
}
.button--move{
 transform: translateY(100px);
}
```

".button--move" its a class that you can add later to apply the animation

Now you can remove this two line of code

```
document.getElementById("LoginButtonS").style.display = "block"; /*Gets button 
that 
can actually complete an action sequence as the other will not work. */
document.getElementById("LoginButtonS").style.transitionDuration = "2s";
```

Now the last thing to do is to show the new form and add this new class "button--move" to the second button in the moment you want to move it with javascript, you can use querySelector again like this.

```
document.querySelector(".loginForm").style.opacity = 1;
document.querySelector('.new-button').classList.add("button--move");
```

You can change the class of the element with classList, I use add() to add the new class with the animation

And now you are ready.

Finally Here is the all the javascript file with the changes

```
function moveLogin() {

 document.querySelector('.windowtext').style.display = "none";

 document.querySelector(".loginForm").style.opacity = 1; 
 document.querySelector('.new-button').classList.add("button--move");
}
```

And the new css file

```
.loginForm {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.new-button{
  display: block;
  transition: all 2s ease-in;
}
.button--move {
  transform: translateY(100px);
}
```

There are more things you can do like use arrow functions or eventListener instead of call the functions inline but you will learn that on time.

Hope that helps!